# div onmouseout not as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

Text and sample code adapted from http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-65078.html, may not reflect actual question:

I have a div and then a div with a nested  table inside it: also there is some div outside the parent div.

```
<div onmousemove="move()" onmouseout="out()">
  <div id="dvRep"> </div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>ITEM 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ITEM 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ITEM 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ITEM 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ITEM 5</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="divChartPopupMenu">
    Hide me.     
</div>
```

Whenever I move my mouse within the div it correctly calls the move function, but the `onmouseout` attribute doesn't work like I thought. I thought that the `out()` function would only be called if you moved your mouse off the div, but `out()` is called whenever I move off one of the table rows. So if my mouse is on a row and I move to the next row it calls `out()`. I want `out()` to be called only when the user moves off the entire div. any ideas?

What I am trying is on out function I am hiding another div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suggest you to read this article on 3 phases of javascript events.
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

in the function move or out, you can check if the srcElement(IE) or target(W3C) has an id called dvRep..

it should look something like this:

```
function out(event)
{
   event.stopPropagation(); //cancel bubbling

   ele = event.target || event.srcElement
   if (ele.id === "dvRep"){  
      //your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`onmouseleave` is the thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're having issue with event bubbling.

When you hover a `tr` you're mouse is no longer 'in' the `div` - therefore when you move between them you're going `tr (out)` -> `div (in)` -> `div (out)` -> `tr (in)`. That's why you're `out()` function is being called between `tr`'s.

Useful reading:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events#Common.2FW3C_events