# onmouseout function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  small image-like thumbnail inside a div written with `onmouseout` function.

```html
<div onmouseout="chng()">
    <!-- Image Here -->
</div>
```

With the function `chng` defined as:

```
function chng(){
  alert('Hi');
}
```

My problem is that when I move my mouse pointer just a little it alerts!

What I want is only the alert comes if the mouse pointer is entirely outside of the div.

Comment: There is absolutely no AJAX, jQuery or PHP in the code that you posted.

Comment: use mouseleave event

Comment: possible duplicate of [div onmouseout does not work as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094071/div-onmouseout-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: Apparently, though, the onmouseout function *is* working properly, you just want a different event.

Comment: can you please share some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can help:

```
<div id="my_div">image here</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#my_div").hover(function(){
        // Put here some action for onMouseOver
    }, function(){
        // Put here some action for onMouseOut
    });
});
</script>
```

Or even:

```
<div id="my_div">image here</div>

<script>
$( "#my_div" ).mouseout(function() {
    // Put here some action for onMouseOut
});
</script>
```

Comment: hover will trigger, when take your mouse inside the div, but the actual question in on mouse out.

Comment: Check the second function with "// Put here some action for onMouseOut"

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
  <script language="javascript">
    function chng()
    {
        alert("mouseout");
     }
   </script>
  <body>
    <div onmouseout="chng()">
      //Image Here
      </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```